# Set operations on two search result sets

Tags: search, filter, data-tables

I have this fairly typical search/filter page that the user can use to view a specific set of `customer` objects. I would like to be able to perform "set operations" (union, intersection, difference, etc.) on two different search result sets.

For example, I could have a result set for customers that like red shirts, and one for customers that were born in January. I want to be able to do a do a "set difference" operation, such that I the resulting set would be the customers that like red shirts but were not born in January.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Nick, and welcome to UX.SE.  As it stands now your question is a poor fit for this site as it doesn't pose a specific UX problem.  You're sating you entire problem and then asking for solution suggestions without showing what specific UX problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hi Nick, I agree with John. The most common approach (that I know of at least) is to use a minus sign before the search parameters you want to exclude in the result. If you've thought of this but discarded it then say why you've done so. And describe which problems you personally see with designing this feature/control and what aspects you'd like help with. Not a mere "help me in this task".

Comment: Somebody edited my post poorly. I am looking for patterns dealing with "Set Operations" specifically, applied to result sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still not clear. You've stated your needs, you have laid your cards on the table... so what do you need? a solution? a suggestion? or perhaps an opinion?

Assuming its a "way" I make my post & reply.

**Set Operation? Think Venn Diagrams**

They best represent all possible operations in a way anyone could digest. How? Look at the illustration below:

Using **color merge** I represent a set of people who like red shirts and were born in January. Similarly you can use **color inverse** to represent the other scenario.

[image]

In a HTML-table or in a Search result panel - I can do a similar color (on rows and columns) based representation to distinguish between results optimal to the selected operation. [Check out this example for more ideas and formula](http://www.benfrederickson.com/2013/05/09/venn-diagrams-with-d3.js.html).

**Cool story so far, How do I construct such a search bar / widget?**

If you want to torment your end-users, feel free to use [+] [-] icons and complex filter mechanism in the search text area. OR If you prefer a smooth easy solution try *[natural language forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_user_interface)* as seen [here](http://escapeflight.com/), and here is [the code](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/21/natural-language-form-with-custom-input-elements/)

and here is another illustration:

[image]

Replace the fixed AND with OR, or even leave that as an interactive field for the end-user to play with.

Comment: I love the color merge idea! Your answer is incredibly helpful, thanks a ton!

Comment: Tip for your programmers, when you do color merges - use actual mixing and not opacity control for better results. Try this http://www.andysoiron.de/demos/color_mixer

Comment: for mixing more than 2 colors, you can get answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819058/mixing-two-colors-naturally-in-javascript